# tfs get files between changeset range

Tags: tfs

I would like to get files in TFS between 2 changeset range. (times the range might be in between as the development goes on)

This will me apply database patch within the changeset range only.

Currently there is an option in Visual studio to only view files between 2 changeset range. But i would like to get the files in that range.  Is there an option from cmdline to do this?

Later on i would like to put this as a job in Jenkins. I would appreciate if anyone knows how to fetch files between 2 changeset range.

Thanks.
Raja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything available out of box. Powertools tfpt getcs let you download specific changelist, so you can do it in the loop (powershell maybe). You can also create two worksaces, download repository in the version as of beginning of the range onto one workspace, in the second workspace download end of the range and diff them.v